# Simple online game servers monitor

Tags: c++

I want to make a tool that runs on win32 to monitor our online game servers. The servers actually are .exe files. I need to know whether they have crashed so I can restart them. Therefore, the tool will have 2 main features:

1. Frequently check a list of the server programs to see whether they are running or not
2. Reopen the executable of any server that has crashed

Does anyone have any idea or knows an API to start with?

Comment: Blindly reopening a serving because it crashed doesn't seem very sensible. What if it crashed because of a disk error, or ran out of memory? If you just keep respawning the process you'd run in to a lot of trouble.

Comment: Yes Alex. Absolutely, I must debug and find the error. However, I want to ensure that in the meantime there is at least one server running

Comment: @WhiteMoney do you work at blizzard? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in Win32, you can start out with C# using `System.Diagnostics`

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Then get a process list:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
     Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

And from there it's up to you what you want to do with the info.

Comment: Thank Khoi, I will try your suggestion

Comment: Process is running, does not represent it is responding. In most crashing cases, the process stops responding.

Comment: You're right. But then again, it would be wiser to connect to the server port(s) directly and do some checks there (like a login/data transfer), rather than to monitor processes on the machine itself. OP was asking to monitor them by looking at the processes and I provided a simple solution to get a start on it. But to really check if a process has crashed or not, you'd have to communicate with the process somehow.

Comment: agree. maybe the server can create stub at different feature / function to allow external health check service to probe the status.

Comment: @Khoi I implemented successfully the tool by using your method. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Game servers should produce logs. You should make a service / cron job to monitor the logs. Depends on the contents of logs, your service should act respective actions, e.g. restart service, trigger alarms, etc.

Comment: But in some crash situations, the game servers don't produce any log.

Comment: that's why heartbeat logging are important. Producing logs in regular time interval helps other health check service to know when it "dies".

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is not *exactly* what you asked for, but what about doing the monitoring with a fully-fledged monitoring tool such as [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)? You would of course have to "teach" the monitoring tool about the processes that shall be monitored but you would also profit from its more advanced functions. In the case of Nagios, for example, these would comprise *automatic e-mail notifications*, an online *dashboard* of process status, notifications via SMS etc.

Comment: Nagios can only monitor the overall process status, not to monitor the process itself.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes, but I thought that the poster was interested in this? Nagios is capable of finding out whether a process has shut down (for whatever reason).

Comment: yes, to extend your comment, Nagios can also trigger alerts. Another better choice (though complex), is Zabbix. It can do a lot more things than Nagios.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the game servers using CreateProcess or similar in the win32 api.
You will get back a process handle in the lpProcessInformation parameter.

You can use WaitForSingleObject to WaitForMultipleObjects to wait until that handle is notified which will happen when the process terminates for any reason.